# Itunes Connect - How to delete new version of in app purchase

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I had an In-App purchase item (a non consumable one) up and running.

I accidentally added a new version of the in-app purchase with **Hosting Content with Apple** enabled.
So now I get the message

```
Hosting Content with Apple
You have not delivered any content or your content is still processing. To deliver your content, use the Application Loader app.
```

The previous version was approved, but the new version is pending approval because I have not uploaded content.  So in my app, the in-purchase is not live anymore.

I do not need the new version . Is it possible to delete the new version and revert to the old version itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved! I have emailed to devprograms@apple.com, in my email, i explain problem like above and attach my In App purchase information (App Name, App ID, In App Purchase ID). After that, i received some email from Apple Developer Program Support and App Store Developer Support Escalation Team (itunesconnect@apple.com), and some days later, i log in itunnesconnect, my problem is fixed (delete the new version and revert to the old version itself).

Comment: Woah! Never thought Apple would respond. Will drop in a mail
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the neww version in iTunes Connect.  Go to your app and click on the "manage in app content" button. From there you can select the IAP and delete it.   You will likely have to recreate the old version if it is in no longer present in iTuens connect.

Comment: Yeah but then I would not be able to retain the old product ID right?

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this?